# How to extract a variable from a simple object literal?

Tags: ajax, json

I have created my first AJAX-JSON project without posting any (dumb) questions, except for this one small problem:

```
function processEvent(data)  {  
var evt = $(data).text();
   }
```

When I write alert(evt); I see the following:

```
{meat:'beef',vegetable:'carrots',potato:'mashed'}
```

I can extract the word 'beef' from the variable 'evt' using the following code:

```
  evt.substr(7,4)
```

But if I write:

```
  evt.meat
```

I get an error: undefined.  How can I retrieve the value of the variable 'meat' directly without resorting to string manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `evt` data was JSON you could parse it and get meat attribute. Currently it is not, this `{meat:'beef',vegetable:'carrots',potato:'mashed'}` as JSON would be `{"meat":"beef","vegetable":"carrots","potato":"mashed"}`. Notice the double quotes being used instead of the single and the properties are also quoted.

```
function processEvent(data)  {  
var evt = $(data).text();// === {"meat":"beef","vegetable":"carrots","potato":"mashed"}
    evtObj = $.parseJSON(evt);
    alert(evtObj.meat); //shows beef
}
```

Comment: I tried this, whereupon my MSIE Script debugger tells me there is an invalid character in line 2 of the jQuery code!  **return a.JSON.parse(b);**

Comment: @user1781623 did you change `{meat:'beef',vegetable:'carrots',potato:'mashed'}` to `{"meat":"beef","vegetable":"carrots","potato":"mashed"}`?

Comment: Sorry, after changing all single quotes to double quotes, everything worked! The event data was a string containing ColdFusion variables, which have their own peculiarities concerning quotes. Now everything works! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is because at this point you specifically made `evt` a string.  Depending on what `data` represents (either JSON string data or an object that has been parsed from JSON, or a DOM node - I can't tell which without more context in your code example), you might need to do something to get an object representation.  At a minimum you can do this to parse the string into JSON:

```
var evt = JSON.parse($(data).text());
```

My guess however is that you might already have an object representation, which you are that making into a string by calling `text()`, so there might be some unnecessary serialization/deserialization going on here.

Comment: Mike, in all of the answers above the suggested JSON.parse function throws the error "Invalid character" (MSIE Script debugger). So you were right to wonder what the context was. I used a ColdFusion query and formatted the output server-side, into the curly-bracketed string shown in my question. So it is arriving at the callback function as a string, which may explain the error message. Using $.getJSON didn't get anything from the server page as I now have it written. So I don't know if the server page is usable as it now stands. I think I will try a ColdFusion forum to fix that page.  FrankF

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `JSON.parse()` to convert from the JSON string to the corresponding data.

```
var evt = JSON.parse($(data).text());
console.log(evt.meat);
```

jQuery can do this automatically for you. Either:

1. Call `$.getJSON()` to perform the AJAX call.
2. Specify `dataType: 'json'` in the AJAX call's options parameter.
3. The server sends the header 'Content-type: application/json'

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which I was unable to test properly because I apparently have a major error on the server-side page which sends the data to the callback function.

Comment: After Musa (above) helped me correct the quotes in the data string, your suggestion worked perfectly. Thank you for your help!  Frank

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
var val = obj['meat'];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which I was unable to test properly because I apparently have a major error on the server-side page which sends the data to the callback function.